# Timer Countdown with progress bar C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, timer, progress-bar

I want to sync my progress bar in my project with the timer countdown.

This is what I has now:

```
namespace Timer1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private int counter=80;
        DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int counter = 80;
            timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Interval = 1000;
            timer1.Start();
            textBox1.Text = counter.ToString();
        }


        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            counter--;
            progressBar1.Increment(1);
            if (counter == 0)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
            }
            textBox1.Text = dt.AddSeconds(counter).ToString("mm:ss");
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            textBox1.Clear();
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I want the progress bar to finish when the timer to ends.

[image]

Comment: uh What? Why would a progress bar be based off of time? Also I bet it is because the GUI is not being forced to update

Comment: I realise this is an old post, but progress bars are a ubiquitous for visualising time duration, so much so that many users get frustrated by a task based progress bar that progresses to a point quickly and waits for a disproportionate amount of time before advancing. Users don't care about the number of tasks, they care about how long it will take. So you will find it a very common requirement to create a time focused progress bar, not a task focused one, especially since the explosion of mobile farming games.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the `progressBar1` to have its [`.Step`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar(v=vs.110).aspx) and `Maximum` properties match the `Interval` and `counter` variable. For example:

```
    private int counter = 80;
    DateTime dt = new DateTime();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // The max is the total number of iterations on the 
        // timer tick by the number interval.
        progressBar1.Max = counter * 1000;
        progressBar1.Step = 1000;

        timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Start();
        textBox1.Text = counter.ToString();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter--;

        // Perform one step...
        progressBar1.PerformStep();

        if (counter == 0)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }
        textBox1.Text = dt.AddSeconds(counter).ToString("mm:ss");
    }
```

Comment: david, can you help me if i want make it work with input for timer with textBox?